# Recognize multi-part shapes in image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Is this possible in OpenCV or other image processing library?

[image]

It should find 3 Shape1 and 2 Shape2. (Meaning it has to process scaling and rotation) And give a position.

I am kind of new to opencv and do not know which algorithm or functions to use to do this. Any help would be very appreciated especially any code. Would the 2 unconnected parts in Shape1 cause problems in detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the **Chamfer** algorithm.

OpenCV has a CPP example in `opencv/samples/cpp/chamfer.cpp`.

Below is an older version I found via google:

https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/chamfer.cpp?rev=4194